# How to run javascript(external url) in adress bar in Safari

Tags: javascript

I need to Run javascript in adress bar.where the js code is contained in external URL.

```
javascript:(a = (b = document).createElement(“script”)).src = “//domain.com/hi.js”, b.body.appendChild(a); void(0)
```

The above code works in IE,firefox and chrome,But not on SAFARI...some one help me to make this work in safari,thanks

Comment: javascript:alert("hi"); works in safari,,,but i am wondering why above code not working

Comment: Have you tried the string delimiters `""`/`''` instead of quotation marks `“”`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using fancy quotes (`“”`), which aren't interpreted properly. Try this:

```
javascript:(a = (b = document).createElement("script")).src = "//domain.com/hi.js", b.body.appendChild(a); void(0)
```

All I did was replace the fancy quotes with plain quotes. This should work now.

Comment: Simple way to check if it is working at all: 1. open the console [alt]+[cmd]+i 2. type in the address bar: `javascript:console.log(1)`